# Custom tracelistener freezing GUI in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, tracelistener

Completely rewrote the question as I now have more information about what is happening.

I have a customtracelistener which overrides the writeline method to add strings to a custom observablecollection. This collection class dispatches all notification events to the UI thread to allow other threads to update it, and still allow WPF data binding.

I have a usercontrol which includes a listbox. The listbox binds the observablecollection in the trace listener to it's itemssource.

In my application startup, I set up the windows/usercontrols/viewmodels, and show the window. I then kick off a worker thread that runs some backend processes required for the app. If the background threads do a Trace.WriteLine before the UI thread has completed all the user control setup and databinding, my application deadlocks.

I've been able to somewhat reasonably prove this race condition by adding sleeps and other random long running tasks in the UI thread and/or delaying starting the worker thread to give the UI thread time to complete.

The solution I'm thinking of implementing now is creating a `AppSetupCompleted` method which kicks off the worker threads for all the backend processes, and sending this to the Dispatcher with a Background priority. In theory, should this delay the worker threads until all of the bindings for the WPF controls and viewmodels have been setup successfully?

Comment: turn on catching all thrown exceptions and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like a deadlock or livelock to me... assuming deadlock (low cpu when app freezes), attach a debugger to the application and break it. Look at the call stack of the threads (UI and the one you called Trace.WriteLine from) to see where they are locking.

If you can't figure out that is blocking, add the call stacks to your question, it may help us answer your question.

Comment: Forgive me for being new to this kind of stuff, but how could I go about getting the call stacks for the various threads.

By stepping through the code I found that the worker thread isn't blocking and gets past the Trace.WriteLine call fine. It's just the GUI thread that locks up.

Comment: Your answer definately pointed me in the right direction. It seems that the race condition had to do with the UI thread doing an initial enumeration on the observablecollection while other threads were modifying it. The proper solution would probably be to rewrite the observablecollection to make it actually threadsafe, however I'm not sure I'd be able to do that without completely reimplementing it.

The immediate problem was solved by creating an AppSetupCompleted method for the background tasks. I then call begininvoke with background priority and create a thread to run it.